# XSL converting time value into "minutes/hours/days ago" format

Tags: xml, xslt, date, duration, xslt-1.0

I have an XML feed that I'm transforming using XSL. The date for each post from the XML comes in this format:

> 2011-03-09T10:44:27Z

I'd like to be able to convert it into "50 minutes ago" or "3 days ago" format, is this possible just using XSL or is PHP the 'only' option ?

Comment: What is your target?  If it's a web page, there's also javascript as an option.

Comment: This is using XSL 1.0  , JS not really an option due to the nature of the end deployment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With XSLT 1.0 use Jenny Tenison pure XSLT [implementation](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/difference/date.difference.template.xsl) of EXSLT [`date:difference()`](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/difference/index.html).

As proof of concept, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times">
    <xsl:import href="date.difference.template.xsl"/>
    <xsl:template match="date">
        <xsl:variable name="vDuration">
            <xsl:call-template name="date:difference">
                <xsl:with-param name="start" select="/test/@today" />
                <xsl:with-param name="end" select="." />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="vDays" 
             select="substring-before(substring-after($vDuration,'P'),'D')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vHours" 
             select="substring-before(substring-after($vDuration,'T'),'H')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vMinutes" 
             select="substring-before(substring-after($vDuration,'H'),'M')"/>
        <xsl:if test="$vDays">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($vDays,' days ')"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$vHours">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($vHours,' hours ')"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$vMinutes">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($vMinutes,' minutes ')"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>ago&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<test today="2011-03-09T15:00:00Z">
    <date>2011-03-09T10:44:27Z</date>
    <date>2011-02-09T10:44:27Z</date>
</test>
```

Output:

```
4 hours 15 minutes ago
28 days 4 hours 15 minutes ago
```

Comment: @Flack: "We stand on the shoulders of giants."